# Error de memoria. El proceso en la GPU utiliza la memoria de la CPU/sistema

Tags: python, tensorflow, out-of-memory-error, cuda, gpu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de actualizar la imagen de tensorflow a **22.01-tf2-py3**, los modelos que solía entrenar, ahora me dan un error de memoria. Tensorflow parece estar usando la memoria del sistema y no la de la GPU, y el programa se detiene después de inicializarse.

Después de investigar un poco, he encontrado que el problema es la **memoria de la CPU/sistema** asignada para este proceso cuando estoy corriendo en la **GPU**. Además, el proceso tf en la GPU utiliza mucha más memoria que el tamaño del conjunto de datos.

Por lo que he leído, tensorflow copia el tensor de salida de la memoria de la GPU a la CPU. Lo que no entiendo es por qué este problema aparece después de actualizar la imagen? ¿Y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

#EDIT: Mi bucle grid search contaba con demasiados parámetros, al reducirlo a un único modelo, sí que entrena. ¿Tiene algún sentido? ¿al entrar en el bucle se cargan todos los modelos a priori?

#EDIT2: Si utilizo la imagen de tensorflow a **21.03-tf2-py3** si que me deja entrenar y todo va bien. ¿Por qué pasa esto? ¿Es debido a alguna actualización de tensorflow?

Comment: Hola, Estás en SOes, así que todo va en español. Por favor ve a [edit] y traduce toooooda la pregunta para que recibas respuesta rápidamente